# Drawing a polygon with lines from vertices to the center

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a program that draws a polygon with n sides. I know how to draw the polygon, I am just struggling with another part. I want to have lines from the corners of the polygon to the center of the polygon. I have tried various math equations like s / (2 sin(180 / n)), but I can't get anything to work. Does anyone know of a way to do this? My code for drawing a simple polygon is below.

```
def polygon(t, n, l, a):
#t = turtle
#n = number of sides
#l = length
#a = angle
   for i in range(n):
      t.forward(l)
      t.left(360 / n)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can work out the trigonometry to do this, and there are examples of such if you seach SO.  Here's one approach:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import pi, sin

def polygon(turtle, sides, length):
    angle = 2 * pi / sides
    radius = length / 2 / sin(angle / 2)
    towards_center = angle / 2 + pi / 2

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(radius)
    turtle.left(towards_center)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(towards_center)
        turtle.forward(radius)
        turtle.backward(radius)  # undo forward(radius)
        turtle.right(towards_center)  # undo turtle.left(towards_center)
        turtle.left(angle)

screen = Screen()
yertle = Turtle()
yertle.radians()  # switch turtle to radians to match math
yertle.dot()  # mark the center of our screen for reference

polygon(yertle, 5, 100)

yertle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Tacking advantage of turtle's own capabilities, we can also do:

```
def polygon(turtle, sides, length):
    angle = 2 * pi / sides
    radius = length / 2 / sin(angle / 2)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-radius)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.circle(radius, angle, steps=1)
        heading = turtle.heading()
        position = turtle.position()
        turtle.home()
        turtle.setposition(position)
        turtle.setheading(heading)
```

[image]